# Best way to present a list form to users?

Tags: workflow, list-form, form

Whats the best way to present a list form to users? We are just starting to convert some of our dead-tree documents into SharePoint forms and workflows. What is the best way to present these forms without making users click *Add New Form*? Many people who have no SharePoint experience do no realize the little link under a list will get them their form. I want to present this so it is easily understood and so that we do not have to train everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I've done in the past are:

- Making a link list dedicated as the central new form list, one click access to enter any form
- Created several buttons that link to the new forms
- In some custom dashboards, I've used jQuery and Lytebox techniques to open forms in modal windows (in Sharepoint 2007)

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath forms are pretty powerful, and can be used for stand-alone forms published to form libraries, or customized as list view forms. If you don't want to depend on InfoPath, you can always customize list views with SharePoint Designer, the out of box WebParts like the XsltListViewWebPart and some custom XSLT, or you can get creative with JavaScript or Silverlight.

I generally prefer InfoPath, but it does require Server edition (not available on Foundation).

Comment: We are using InfoPath for our froms, but is there an easy way to show the form without everyone having to click _Add New Item_? This is not obvious to a lot of people who are not used to SharePoint.